# How to remove "Santa's on his way!" from Google chrome Home page?

Tags: google-chrome

Today suddenly I'm seeing `Santa's on his way! Follow his journey around the world` pointing to [Google Santa Tracker](https://santatracker.google.com/?utm_source=en-GB&utm_medium=hpp&utm_campaign=2019-tracker-hpp).

[image: Google chrome home page with Google Santa link]

This is unnecessary for me and I want to remove this. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Use another search engine or browser.

Comment: Try using inspect element and remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not remove it because it is part of that page(coded in that page)

google made that several occasion or festival so you can not remove it instead try another browser